# open html file in php email

Tags: php, html

I currently have this code trying to open html file and set that to $mail_body.

```
include_('../forms/promo_email_form.html');

        $mail_body = '';


        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: info@grillontherock\r\n";
```

I've seen people just putting regular html file into $mail_body but I have massive html file which I cannot and easier for me to use.

Can you guys give exmaple code? Thanks!

Comment: Include includes the file, you want the data as a string, right? Use `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, use `file_get_contents` instead of `include`:

```
$mail_body = file_get_contents('../forms/promo_email_form.html');
```